# Can I set a value to a variable via alias of it in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to set a value via alias of it in bash, like following.

```
ORIGINAL_VALUE="a"
ALIAS="ORIGINAL_VALUE"
"$ALIAS"="b"  # This line does not work.
echo "value is $ORIGINAL_VALUE"
```

The result I expect is

```
value is b
```

Now I know it is possible to read the value of ORIGINAL_VALUE via ALIAS by

```
${!ALIAS}
```

But, unfortunately, I don't know how to set the value of ORIGINAL_VALUE via ALIAS, like "$ALIAS"="b", which does not work.

Some who has a solution or a suggestion, please tell me it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: `alias` is a shell keyword -- you might try to use a different term to avoid confusing folks about your meaning.

Comment: BTW, see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables

Comment: Thank you, Charles Duffy, for giving me a site with comprehensive instruction of reference of variable. By the way, you marked this question as duplicated. Should I delete this question? I am afraid points I offered to contributers are also deleted.

Comment: There's no reason to delete it -- duplicates serve a useful purpose when, as here, they use different enough terms to pose a question to make it more likely for someone who's searching to find a hit on the terms they use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nameref (`bash` 4.3 or later)

```
$ declare -n alias=original_value
$ original_value=a
$ alias=b
$ echo "$original_value"
b
```

Comment: Nice! Never knew that *my* bash can do that.

Comment: Thank you, chepner. It works in my bash. I suppose your answer is the direct answer to my question. Other answers are also great, of course and they may have advantage of compatibility. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `declare`:

```
ORIGINAL_VALUE="a"
ALIAS="ORIGINAL_VALUE"
declare $ALIAS="b"
echo "value is $ORIGINAL_VALUE"
```

Output:

```
value is b
```

Side note: If you put this into a function and want to change the value of a variable from outside the scope of the function this won't work since `declare` would redeclare the variable locally in that case.

Comment: Thank you, hek2mgl. Your solution and side note was great information for me. I need to reset the original variable as global variable. So this time, solution from chepner seems to be better way. Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. I agree that chepner's answer is a better choice if you have bash-4.3 and don't care about other shells.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can trust the variables are safe:

```
eval $ALIAS=b
```

Comment: Thank you Karoly Horvath. I offered a point above.